# Inspect last sibling statement in Go AST?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a static code analyzer in Go. And I have a logic rule that needs to check if resources are released before return, this rule need to audit last statement before return. I notice that the AST walks in depth first, can someone give a hint about my rule? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Before you start reinventing the wheel, have you came across [this](https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/tree/master/staticcheck)?

Comment: I want to customize my specific rules, but maybe I can use its skeleton. Thanks.